# I'm trying to responsively align the images of two articles. The heights of the containers are unknown. How do I do this?

Tags: css

Here is my html:

```
<article class="featured">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x100/ff0000">
    <p>
        <!--Text-->
    </p>
</article>
<article class="sub-featured">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x100/00ff00">
    <p>
        <!--Text-->
    </p>
</article>
<article class="sub-featured">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x100/0000ff">
    <p>
        <!--Text-->
    </p>
</article>
```

And my sass:

```
body{
 margin:0;
 img{width:100%}
 article.featured{
    p{width:50%}
 }
 article.sub-featured{
    width:50%;
    margin-left:auto;
 }
}
```

Here is the html so far:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

But the catch is I want it to look like that when I shrink and expand the screen---so that the bottom of the green image aligns with the bottom of the red image at all screen widths. So I can't simply apply position:relative to the articles. And I can't use a CSS transformation because the height of the article is unknown.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```css
.redImage {
  position: relative;
}

.redImage img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

article {
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}

.specialImage {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.specialImage img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="redImage">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/1200x3:1/f00/fff" />
</div>
<article>
  <h3>Introduction</h3>
  <p>The Alaskan Rolling Rock plans an escape from a sudsy IPA a flirty Dixie Beer. A grizzly beer greedily can be kind to a paternal Long Trail Ale. A sake bomb around a bud light, a PBR, and the frozen Budweiser are what made America great! A crazy pool
    table caricatures the mug. When a Sam Adams for a Dixie Beer self-flagellates, a Bacardi Silver returns home.</p>
</article>
<article>
  <div class="specialImage">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/1200x3:1/ccc/f00" />
  </div>
  <h3>A polar bear beer</h3>
  <p>When some Dixie Beer takes a coffee break, the optimal shot beams with joy. Any PBR can derive perverse satisfaction from an Octoberfest, but it takes a real Miller to wastedly recognize a scooby snack near the coors light. A milwakees best for a miller
    light ignores a chain saw. A psychotic Hazed and Infused buries a bill. An Ipswich Ale about a Stella Artois gives lectures on morality to a coors light of a scooby snack.
    <h3>The fried Red Stripe</h3>
    <p>Any Heineken can dumbly graduate from the porter living with the Rolling Rock, but it takes a real keg to knowingly bury a tooled Lone Star. A scooby snack negotiates a prenuptial agreement with a bar tab. An Amarillo Pale Ale beams with joy, because
      a Long Trail Ale of a Sam Adams requires assistance from another frozen bar tab. When a miller light near a PBR ceases to exist, the Imperial Stout about a booze ruminates. A beer gives the last beer to the power drill drink.</p>
</article>
```

If not, please clarify.

Change the dummyimgs ratios and you'll see it always works (even when the small image's height is bigger than the big image's - the small image will have the head cropped in this special scenario).

<kbd>[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/xa34dvdc/)</kbd>

Comment: This is great, thanks! Just going to spend a bit of time to dissect to make sure.

Comment: If it really helps you, I can make it work on your markup too. But I'm a dev. When there's no fence, I don't build one. You never said markup has to stay.

Comment: I'm going through now and trying to see what you did. I'll get back to you afterwards. Markup doesn't have to stay but hopefully it makes sense and is not to hack-y. But no worries either way. I really appreciate the help!